# Setting up a start date and a end date to store into a firebase cloud?

Tags: java, android, firebase, calendar

Currently, I am creating a calendar app that will essentially have an employee choose a start date and an end date. The duration chosen between these dates will be the employees chosen holiday.

Now the problem is that I need to store 2 dates, which are the start date and the end date, into a firebase database. I intend to use this information later on so that I can compare the dates with other employees who may take the same week off (so validation will be needed). However, with my current code, I am only able to create a start date but not an end date, I am also unable to store information into the cloud, but I struggle to understand how I can retrieve the data in its current form.

For further clarification what I am trying to achieve is: I will have 2 buttons, `startDateBtn` and `endDateBtn`, both will initialize a calendar, the dates chosen will be stored/returned as strings and the data will be retrieved by a 3rd button called `bookDatesBtn`. This button will save the data into the cloud.

What I have tried:

- Used a boolean variable set to false, if the `startDateBtn` is initialized the boolean variable is set to true, this will trigger an if-else statement and will set information for start date as a string. If the `endDateBtn` is initialized then the boolean variable will be set to false, this will keep information for the end date as a string.

**DatePickerFragment.Java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);

    }
    
}
```

**HolidayScreen.Java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class HolidayScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_holiday_screen);

//        //Setting listener for start date button for picking date
        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startDateButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "start date picker");

            }
        });

        //Setting listener for start date button for picking date
        Button endButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endDateButton);
        endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "end date picker");
            }
        });

        //Setting listener for storing both dates into the cloud
        Button bookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bookButton);
        bookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //This is where all the logic will go, so i will retrieve the start date information and then the-
                //-end date information and store into firebase database
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());


            TextView startTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startDateText);
            startTextView.setText("Start Date: " + currentDateString);
    }

}
```

The XML file will be provided on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my personal use code and it's working fine for my all device I think you should try this code...

I want to know which firebase database you have to use so after I can suggest it .. firebase real-time OR Cloud-firestore for store data...

**for the whole code Visit My Code Link - https://github.com/axarlotwala/CafeDelear/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/cafedelear/aksha/cafedelear/Fragment/ProductOfferFragment.java**

```
/*method of start offer*/

private void offerStart() {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    myear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    dmonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mdate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            start_date.setText(year + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }
    },myear,dmonth,mdate);
    dialog.show();

    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}

private void offerEnd(){

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    myear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    dmonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mdate = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    calendar.roll(Calendar.DATE,1);


    dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            end_date.setText(year + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }
    },myear,dmonth,mdate);
    dialog.show();

    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    //if offer end date is selected is also start Offer date then offer end time is Date-23-59-59
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is you can understand for previous or new date in your textview first set then use it

previous date:

```
     public void previousDate(Context context, TextView textView) {
    mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarAlarm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
            new DatePickerDialog(context, (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                String datetime = dateFormat.format(mCalendarAlarm.getTime());
                textView.setText(datetime);
            }, mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().
            setMaxDate(mCalendarAlarm.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

for next date:

```
public void NextDate(Context context, TextView textView) {
    mCalendarAlarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    mCalendarAlarm.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
            new DatePickerDialog(context, (view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth) -> {
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                mCalendarAlarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
                String datetime = dateFormat.format(mCalendarAlarm.getTime());
                textView.setText(datetime);
            }, mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    mCalendarAlarm.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().
            setMinDate(mCalendarAlarm.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```